# C# Membership registration and Login Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership

When I register user and then LogIn I get

```
WebContext.Current.User.GetIdentity();
```

And I get UserName How Can I change user identity and set email or Guid as identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Registration page to set Username = Email Address

Comment: @ John Mc I kill few hours whil search some code or blog post about this question. But Then I decide do like you told me ;) But I think this is little incorrect. Or I must add validation to validate email and username_email.

Comment: Yes you should add validation to ensure a valid email address is provided. You should only be asking for email address once and then set User.Email and User.Username to whatever is provided. On your form, added a RegEx validator to validate that it's in the correct format. Easy :-)